# how can I set a function not to call when a condition meet - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, function

I have an array of objects.

```
let items = [
        {
            type: "Shirt",
            gender: ["Men", "Women", "Boys", "Girls"],
            size: "Small",
    
        },
        {
            type: "Shirt",
            gender: ["Men", "Women", "Boys"],
            size: "Medium",
    
        },
        {
            type: "Shirt",
            gender: ["Men", "Women"],
            size: "Large",
    
        },
    ];

    let filteredArr = [];
    filteredArr = items;
```

I am searching for a `Shirt` then for a `Size` in `Shirt` by using two different functions. My 1st function is for searching a `Shirt` namely `fetchItemsByType` and 2nd function is for searching a specific `Size` in `Shirt`. My 2nd function's name is `fetchItemsBySize`. I want to display my output in two different scenario.

1. When entered `Shirt` only - Result(s) should be seen of all `Shirts` available.
2. When entered `Size` with `Shirt` - Only result(s) of specific `Size` for `Shirt` should be seen.

I tried by my own but I'm getting result of all `Shirt` available too with a result of `Size` with `Shirt`. I don't want to show the result(s) of `Shirt` in my final output when `Size` is entered and vice versa. Below are the inputs and code with output which I tried.

1st Input:

```
let searchForType = "Shirt";
```

Code:

```
function fetchItemsByType() {
    let isItemAva = filteredArr.filter(obj => obj["type"] === searchForType);
    isItemAva.forEach(obj => {
        for (let i = 0; i < obj["type"].length; i++) {
            if (obj["type"] === searchForType) {}
        }
          document.write(obj["type"] + " of " + obj["size"] + " size is Available for " + obj["gender"] + "<br>" + "<br>")
        });
    return isItemAva;
}
let getItemsByType = fetchItemsByType();

if (searchForType === searchForType) {
    console.log(getItemsByType);
}
```

Output

```
Shirt of Small size is Available for Men,Women,Boys,Girls

Shirt of Medium size is Available for Men,Women,Boys

Shirt of Large size is Available for Men,Women
```

2nd Input:

```
let searchForSize = "Small"; (Note: Both searchForType = "Shirt"; and searchForSize = "Small"; are entered now)
```

Code:

```
function fetchItemsBySize() {
        let isSizeAva = getItemsByType.filter(obj => obj["size"] === searchForSize);
        isSizeAva.forEach(obj => {
            for (let i = 0; i < obj["size"].length; i++) {
                if (obj["size"] === searchForSize) {}
            }
            document.write(obj["type"] + " of " + obj["size"] + " size is Available for " + obj["gender"] + "<br>" + "<br>")
           });
        return isSizeAva;
     }
     let getItemsBySize = fetchItemsBySize();

if (searchForSize === searchForSize) {
    console.log(getItemsBySize);
}
```

Output:

*Shirt of Small size is Available for Men,Women,Boys,Girls*

*Shirt of Medium size is Available for Men,Women,Boys*

*Shirt of Large size is Available for Men,Women*

**Shirt of Small size is Available for Men,Women,Boys,Girls**

In above output(my resultant output), all *Italics* shouldn't be included but only **Bold** line should get appeared. How can I achieve this? Need assistance.

Comment: All your if statements and for loops are illogical, unnecessary and harms performance. Consider put your code in a code snippet next time.

Answer (score 0):

Your can  filter your items array as follow

```js
let items = [
        {
            type: "Shirt",
            gender: ["Men", "Women", "Boys", "Girls"],
            size: "Small",
    
        },
        {
            type: "Shirt",
            gender: ["Men", "Women", "Boys"],
            size: "Medium",
    
        },
        {
            type: "Shirt",
            gender: ["Men", "Women"],
            size: "Large",
    
        },
    ];
function searchByType(items, type){
  return items.filter((item)=>{
    if(item.type==type){
      return item
    }
  })
}

function searchBySize(items, size){
  return items.filter((item)=>{
    if(item.size==size){
      return item
    }
  })
}
 
const search = searchBySize(searchByType(items,'Shirt'),'Large');
console.log('search ', search);
```